# How to delete a part of data in a relation ManyToMany

Tags: php, symfony

I am a beginner on Symfony 4 and after having followed some tutorials, I am working on a project to improve myself!

It is an event manager with registrations of participants with a back office. As a visitor, I can register for one or more events from a select list of a bootstrap form.
Once registered, the administrator can access his back office and see who has registered in this or that event by selecting a specific event and view the list.

My problem is that if the administrator decides to remove a participant from an event, the participant is deleted in the database and therefore all the events to which it has registered. While I would like it to be removed only from the event in question.

I think I need to create a query in the repository file of my event ...

Here are some parts of the code that I think is useful.

My Entity Participant.php who has a relationship ManyToMany:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", inversedBy="participants")
 */
private $workshops;
```

Entity Event.php file :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Participant", mappedBy="workshops")
 */
private $participants;
```

And in one of my controllers, here is the function that removes the participant from all events :

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/delete_participant/{id}", name="delete_participant")
*/
    public function deleteParticipant(EntityManagerInterface $manager, Participant $participant) {

        $manager->remove($participant);
        $manager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('danger', "Participant deleted");

        return $this->redirectToRoute("admin_page", [
            'participant' => $participant,
        ]);
    }
```

I have to create a custo request but I block on it.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to remove the reference to the Participant from the Event, not delete the Participant. In other words, remove the (many to many) association, not delete the Participant record outright, which is what you are doing above.

Comment: These associations are stored in an `ArrayCollection` and if memory serves there's a method called `removeElement()` to do this. At a guess, this is probably something like `$event->getParticipants()->removeElement($participant)`. I suspect this has come up on StackOverflow before so have a search for removing (not deleting) associations.

Comment: Hello, your answer is really interesting!

If I understand, I need to transform my function 



`/**
 * @Route("/admin/delete_participant/{id}", name="delete_participant")
*/
    public function deleteParticipant(EntityManagerInterface $manager, Participant $participant, Event $event) {

        $event->getParticipants()->removeElement($participant);
        $manager->flush();
...`



That's right ? Because if I do that, I've an error
**App\Entity\Event object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.**
It's the {id} in the url who make this error right ?

Comment: Yes, by default at least—`@ParamConverter` will infer the entity from the type hint and use the id. You can also configure it to use other (usually unique or compound) properties. Check that the file name, class name and entity namespace for `Event` is correct. You may want to ask a new question about this if you continue to experience problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution without using **JoinTable**

```
/**
 * @Route("admin/{id}/edit_event/", name="delete_participant")
 */
 public function deleteParticipant(int $id, Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $event = $em->getRepository(Event::class)->find($id);

        $participant = $em->getRepository(Participant::class)->find($request->request->get('participant_id'));

        $event->removeParticipant($participant);

        $em->persist($event);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse([
            'event' => $event,
        ]);
}
```

I use this function in my controller with an AJAX call in my Twig template!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **[@JoinTable](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association)** if you're using **MANY TO MANY Relationship**.

Here i'm giving you steps which might be help you:

1) in Participant.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", inversedBy="participants")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="participants_event",
     *         joinColumns = {@ORM\JoinColumn(name="participants_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *         inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="workshops_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
 */
private $participantsEvent;
```

2) in Event.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Participant", mappedBy="participantsEvent")
 */
private $participants;
```

3) Generate Getter -Setter Method

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate
```

4) Doctrine Schema Update

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

5) Remove participant

```
//$event  Object Of Event
//$participants Object of Participant
$event->removeParticipants($participants);
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer,

I've try your solution but I've the same problem that I wrote above.

`/**
     * @Route("/admin/delete_participant/{id}", name="delete_participant")
     */
    public function deleteParticipant(EntityManagerInterface $manager, Participant $participant, Event $event) {

        $event->removeParticipants($participant);
        $manager->flush();
...`

If I do that, I've this error
**App\Entity\Event object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation**
And I think it's the variable {id} in my url who make this error...

Comment: Great answer. @Galn89 if you find the answer useful, don't forget to upvote and mark it as the answer when you can.

Comment: @DarraghEnright Yes I will upvote, I just waiting to see if Mitesh will come back to see my answer.

Comment: @Galn89 Yes, id must be associate with Event entity. Don't use as $manager and $participant as parameter instead put in action like, $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); $participant = <get by doctrine query>

Comment: @MiteshVasava Hello and thank you for your answer! I'm sorry but I don't understand where to put the line
`$event->removeParticipants($participants);`
When you say $participant= <get by doctrine query>, do you mean something like 
`$participant2 = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Participant')
            ->find($participant->getId());
` ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: @MiteshVasava Great! And can you just tell me where I need to put the step 5 ? It's only on this step where I block...

Comment: @Galn89 in your deleteParticipant function